# Order and Dimension of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

What is the difference between the "order" of a vector and "dimension" of a vector? I am really confused and clueless after reading about them. It will be great if someone can differentiate them for me.
Thanks :-)

Comment: Can you give us a context for the '*order* of a vector'? The dimension rather makes sense, it would be the dimension of the ambient space that contains the given vector, or equivalently, the *number of its coordinates*, supposed it is coordinated in some basis.

Comment: In Springer text Matrix Algebra page 4, it is written. For a positive integer "n", a vector (or n-vector) is an n-tuple, ordered (multi)set or array on "n" numbers called elements or scalars. The number of elements is called the order , or sometimes the length of the vector

Comment: Ahh, then it's just the same as dimension of the ambient space (the space of real $n$-tuples for order $n$).

Comment: Ok, now on page 15 it says. "The order of a vector space is the order of vectors in space. Because the maximum number of n-vectors that can form a linearly independent set is 'n' as we showed above the "order" of a vector space is greater than or equal to the dimension of the vector space. How can order be greater than dimension? Could you please clarify with an example? thanks

Comment: The only possible way for that is to consider *subspaces* of the space of $n$-tuples (denoted by $\Bbb R^n$). An easy example is the set of vectors of the form $(a, a) $. It is a subspace (closed under all linear combinations) of dimension 1, if you draw it on the coordinate plane, it's just the diagonal line (but we could take any line crossing the origin).

Comment: So the dimension of (a, a) is two. So what is the order?

Comment: No. The dimension of the *(sub)space* is 1, and the order of its elements (like $(3,3)$) is 2.

Comment: How did you get the dimension as 1?

Comment: It's the dimension of the *(sub)space* generated by the single vector $(1,1)$.